# 2GB vs 4GB Graphics card Memory for playback and encoding of Videos in Adobe Premiere CC

Tags: video, premiere, hardware, encoding

While looking into buying a new **graphics card** for the **editing, live playback and encoding of videos** in the new 64bit Premiere Pro CC, I was wondering about:

**1) how and when a graphics card's memory is utilised or loaded?**
**2) when would one benefit from the higher graphics card Memory?**
Would I benefit during editing/live playback, or when encoding and exporting a video?

As of summer 2014 the Nvidia GTX 770 seems a sweetspot in terms of price/performance that grasped my attention. This model is abvailable in 2GB and 4GB versions. I will be using some filters and will be using Magic Lantern RAW 1920x840 @ 24 fps footage timeline for short videos of around 4 minutes. Thanks!